# Multi-player RTS with simultaneous control and late joining?

Tags: game

I’m looking for a coop real time strategy game that allows this:

1. Two players start a networked game, against each other,
2. Later, additional players may join the game, on a side of their choosing. Then
3. all players on each team can control all units etc. independently and simultaneously.

Preferably it should be Free Software and runnable on Linux.

Does such a game exist? If not, what free RTS would likely be easiest to patch to support that?

Comment: There is a ticket for this in the [OpenRA bug tracker](http://bugs.openra.net/3793) (but no progress ATM).

Answer (score 2):

I know a game that allows points 1 and 3, I don't really know about 2 (late joining).

[Warzone2100](http://wz2100.net/)

It's Free Software and runs on Linux. It's actively developed and it has a modding community too, maybe post your idea on [the forums](http://forums.wz2100.net/) and see if it gets some traction ;)

BTW it uses Qt at its core (they recently switched and cleaned up the code), so it should be easy to pick up modding if you have a good knowledge of C++ and game development.

Comment: If 3 is really supported, then maybe 2 is not too hard; depending on how the network code is organized. Maybe I should have a look at some quiet weekend.

Answer (score 0):

One series you could try are [FreeCiv](https://play.freeciv.org/) and [FreeCol](http://www.freecol.org/download.html). These are open source versions of Sid Meyer's Civilization and Colonization.

They seem to meet all of the requirements.

Originally, FreeCiv was a client, but they seem to have gone the route of HTML5, whereas FreeCol is a java client, it should run anywhere. They both support joining multiplayer games late.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure they also support the third conditions (all players on each team can control all units etc. independently and simultaneously.)?

Comment: I can't see why not, as each player controls their own independant nation. I'd have to test it later to verify however...

Comment: If each player controls thier own independent nation, then this contradicts my requirements that later-joiners can control the *same* nation as the player that they are teaming up with.